# Proving the existence/non-existence of prime elements

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, prime-numbers, factorial

No answers, please. Hints only.

Given that $n$ is a positive integer and $x=(n+1)!+2$, I want to prove whether or not the sequence $x, x+1, \cdots, x+(n-1)$ contains no primes.

I did a lot of algebra to find that $x+(n-1)$ is no more than just $(n+1)[n!+1]$. But I'm not sure what to do with this, I'm still unsure what this says about the conclusion.

Comment: Can you show that $2$ divides $(n+1)!+2$? Can you generalize from here?

Comment: If 2 divides $n$, then 2 must divide $(n+1)$, therefore it divides $(n+1)!$. It's a given that $2|2$, so then $2|(n+1)!+2$. Right?

Comment: @Lex_i Right, except that if $2$ divides $n$ then you can directly conclude that $2$ divides $(n+1)!$. Now, does $3$ divide $(n+1)! + 3$? Does $4$ divide $(n+1)! + 4$? And so on.

Comment: The idea to show that $2 \mid (n+1)!$ is right, and your argument from there onwards is right. But the way you have shown that $2 \mid (n+1)!$ is slightly inaccurate. Try to use the fact that $(n+1)!$ is the product of the first $n+1$ positive integers, and show that atleast one of these $n+1$ positive integers is divisible by $2$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense now, thank you! If you want, you can write that as an answer and i'll mark it correct

Comment: Note that in your last paragraph, you also showed $(n+1)$ divides $x + (n-1)$.  There's a pattern here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $(n+1)!$ is the product of the first $n+1$ positive integers. Can you show that $2$ divides $(n+1)!+2$? Can you generalize from here?